# Parse text file in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file like this:

```
WP 000 Name Mumbai ANCHORAGE
Lat  36°10.140000N Lon   5°23.860000W
RL (Rumb Line)
XTE= 0.30nm
TurnRadius= 0.50nm


WP 001 Name Mumbai PILOT  OFF
Lat  36°08.200000N Lon   5°23.770000W
RL (Rumb Line)
XTE= 0.20nm
TurnRadius= 0.00nm
```

I want to create a dataframe from this and the columns are given below but can be different based on the files.

```
WP Name PILOT LAT Lon RL XTE TurnRadius
```

can anybody suggest any proper way to solve this?

Any help would be appeciated.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like for the input in your example?

Comment: Your first block has no `PILOT` so what do you want to do with it? Also dataframe is supposed to be structured data, but in this case it's semi-structured so it's better to preprocess the file before you create the dataframe.

Comment: @knh190, The pilot has OFF as its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I have read the file and parsed the parameters. You can make further enhancements to the code.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from collections import ChainMap
s = []
with open('readerfile.txt') as rf:
    s = [i.strip('\n') for i in rf.readlines()]


sections = []
while(len(s)):
    try:
        if s.index('') != 0:
            sections.append(s[:s.index('')])
        if len(s)>1:
            s = s[s.index('')+1:]
        else:
            s = []
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sections.append(s)
        s = []

def get_groups(l):
    d = []
    while(len(l)):
        d.append(l[:2])
        l=l[2:]
    return dict(d)
pd.DataFrame([ChainMap(*[get_groups(j.split() if len(j.split())%2==0 else j.split()+[None]) for j in i]) for i in sections])
```

This renders the below DataFrame:

```
    ANCHORAGE   Lat Lon Name    PILOT   RL  TurnRadius= WP  XTE=
0   NaN 36Â°10.140000N  5Â°23.860000W   Mumbai  NaN None    0.50nm  000 0.30nm
1   NaN 36Â°08.200000N  5Â°23.770000W   Mumbai  OFF None    0.00nm  001 0.20nm
```